Automating Build Dependencies for Different Configurations in Visual Studio Solution
I have a Visual Studio project with two configurations: Debug 32 and Release 32. The project includes a module that has different build dependencies for each configuration:

For Debug 32, the module depends on Library A.
For Release 32, the module depends on Library B.

Currently, when I switch between these configurations, I need to manually update the module's build dependencies through the Solution Explorer to point to the correct library. This is time-consuming, especially when switching configurations frequently.
My question is:
Is there a way to automate this process in Visual Studio, so that the correct build dependency is automatically selected based on the active configuration (Debug 32 or Release 32)?
Ideally, I'd like to set up the project in such a way that it "remembers" the correct dependencies for each configuration, eliminating the need for manual intervention.
I've explored ItemDefinitionGroup in the project files for managing compile and link settings, but I haven't found a straightforward solution for automating build dependency changes for different configurations.
Any suggestions or guidance on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!

Library A and library B are ProjectReferences? Add a Condition on the ProjectReference for each library that tests the value of $(Configuration) or place the ProjectReference for each library within an ItemGroup that is testing the $(Configuration).

Hi @NITIN, did you try to use conditional reference in your project file like below i added?

Hi, thanks for the help, I solved it, by adding conditional reference in .vcxproj file.

As @Jonathan says, you can use conditional reference in your project file to reference a library based on your configurations. Here is detailed information i add.
Open your project file and add additional reference in it.
For example:
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
  <Reference Include="LibraryA">
    <HintPath>..\libs\Debug\LibraryA.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
  <Reference Include="LibraryB">
    <HintPath>..\libs\Release\LibraryB.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>



Yes @Dou Xu-MSFT,as Jonathan suggested,  this is is something I have added in the file and that works for me, it dynamically links the library it needed according to the configuration. Thanks for the help guys.

Glad to hear that this issue doesn't block you anymore. Happy coding
